# SMPS files that are not read by SCIP 6.0

Tags: scip, stochastic

I have a set of SMPS files that are read by Coin-SMI's SMPS reader, but not by SCIP 6.0's. Actually, SCIP 6.0 shows ''Segmentation fault (core dumped)'' when it tries to read .sto file.

Could you take a quick look at it please to see which part is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**SSLP_3_3_3.cor**

```
NAME          SSLP_3_3_3
ROWS
 N  OBJ
 L  CON1
 L  CON2
 L  CON3
 L  CON4
 E  CON5
 E  CON6
 E  CON7
COLUMNS
    MARKER    'MARKER'                'INTORG'
    x[1]      OBJ       69.000000     CON1      1.000000    
    x[1]      CON2      -66.000000  
    x[2]      OBJ       42.000000     CON1      1.000000    
    x[2]      CON3      -66.000000  
    x[3]      OBJ       44.000000     CON1      1.000000    
    x[3]      CON4      -66.000000  
    y[1,1]    OBJ       -21.000000    CON2      21.000000   
    y[1,1]    CON5      1.000000    
    y[1,2]    OBJ       -18.000000    CON3      18.000000   
    y[1,2]    CON5      1.000000    
    y[1,3]    OBJ       -11.000000    CON4      11.000000   
    y[1,3]    CON5      1.000000    
    y[2,1]    OBJ       -21.000000    CON2      21.000000   
    y[2,1]    CON6      1.000000    
    y[2,2]    OBJ       -19.000000    CON3      19.000000   
    y[2,2]    CON6      1.000000    
    y[2,3]    OBJ       -4.000000     CON4      4.000000    
    y[2,3]    CON6      1.000000    
    y[3,1]    OBJ       -6.000000     CON2      6.000000    
    y[3,1]    CON7      1.000000    
    y[3,2]    OBJ       -24.000000    CON3      24.000000   
    y[3,2]    CON7      1.000000    
    y[3,3]    OBJ       -8.000000     CON4      8.000000    
    y[3,3]    CON7      1.000000    
    MARKER    'MARKER'                 'INTEND'
    y0[1]     OBJ       1000.000000   CON2      -1.000000   
    y0[2]     OBJ       1000.000000   CON3      -1.000000   
    y0[3]     OBJ       1000.000000   CON4      -1.000000   
RHS
    rhs       CON1      3.000000      CON2      -0.000000   
    rhs       CON3      -0.000000     CON4      -0.000000   
    rhs       CON5      1.000000      CON6      1.000000    
    rhs       CON7      1.000000    
BOUNDS
 BV BOUND     x[1]    
 BV BOUND     x[2]    
 BV BOUND     x[3]    
 BV BOUND     y[1,1]  
 BV BOUND     y[1,2]  
 BV BOUND     y[1,3]  
 BV BOUND     y[2,1]  
 BV BOUND     y[2,2]  
 BV BOUND     y[2,3]  
 BV BOUND     y[3,1]  
 BV BOUND     y[3,2]  
 BV BOUND     y[3,3]  
ENDATA
```

**SSLP_3_3_3.sto**

```
STOCH         SSLP_3_3_3
SCENARIOS     DISCRETE
 SC SCEN1     'ROOT'    0.333333  PERIOD2
    rhs       CON5      -0.000000   
    rhs       CON6      -0.000000   
    rhs       CON7      -0.000000   
 SC SCEN2     'ROOT'    0.333333  PERIOD2
    rhs       CON6      -0.000000   
 SC SCEN3     'ROOT'    0.333333  PERIOD2
    rhs       CON7      -0.000000   
ENDATA
```

**SSLP_3_3_3.tim**

```
TIME          SSLP_3_3_3
PERIODS       IMPLICIT
    x[1]      CON1      PERIOD1
    y[1,1]    CON2      PERIOD2
ENDATA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCIP expects `rhs` to be written upper case, I don't know what the format defines exactly, but this is actually in line with how sections in mps work. We might change this in the future, but until then, just write `RHS` and everything should work.

Comment: As you said, SCIP reads it well after I changed 'rhs' to 'RHS'. I think this is a minor bug since as far as I know MPS format (for .cor file) does not require specific format on the right hand side column identifier as long as the section identifier 'RHS' presents well. Thanks, Gerald!